# How to access a file from a network folder on macOS with Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am connected to the network folder and can access the file manually, but when I try to access the excel file through pandas from the below path, it  gives me an error.

Path: `"smb://fs3-4-ines.rz.hs-offenburg.de/INES/INES/INES/Wetterdaten/2022/2022-08.xlsx"`

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/fs3-4-ines.rz.hs-offenburg.de/INES/INES/INES/Wetterdaten/2022/2022-08.xlsx'
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: It will be mounted under `/Volumes` in your filesystem. Start a Terminal and run `ls /Volumes` and you'll see it listed. If it appears as `/Volumes/UNIVERSITY`, you can look in there using `ls /Volumes/UNIVERSITY` and then use that in **pandas**.

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project!